# Overriding Magento Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Subtotal

Tags: magento

i would like to override Magento core `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Subtotal` in my custom module.

I have tried the below URL for `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Subtotal` rewite

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total but changes not reflecting.

can any one suggest me explanation in above core path?

Any help much appreciate.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Does Magento continue to use old class or  are you experiencing any error messages? Can you verify that your module is active?

Comment: Overriding file / function not routing in my custom module. i don't know the right syntax for `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Subtotal` rewrite in my config.xml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have money to throw at an IDE, phpstorm with the magicento plugin will do all of the heavy lifting of creating class overrides for you.

You should know how to do this by hand though:

If your only problem is not knowing the correct syntax for your custom module's config, the following should help.  If not, please provide some more information so we can do a better job helping you.

In your custom module's config file you will need to have the following under the `<models>` node:

```
<sales>
    <rewrite>
        <order_invoice_total_subtotal>CompanyName_ModuleName_Model_Sales_Order_Invoice_Total_Subtotal</order_invoice_total_subtotal>
    </rewrite>
</sales>
```

If you would end up wanting to overriding more classes in the sales module, you would just add them to the rewrite node described above.